# Examples of double surface integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, surface-integrals

I'm looking for detailed examples and practical applications of *double surface integrals*. I'm particularly interested in parametric surfaces and numerical integration (quadrature/cubature), though different approaches using other surface descriptions and/or analytical integration are also welcomed.

One application I know of are the *view factors* used in radiative heat transfer (or in radiosity for computer graphics rendering), see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_factor#View_factors_of_differential_areas.

**[Edit]**
The concept of *double line integrals* might be relevant as well, I'd definitely be interested in notes or examples on the topic.

Comment: Double surface integrals come up a lot when studying the interaction of current loops in classical magnetostatics through [Ampere's force law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law). The most common application would probably be the calculation of mutual inductances of particular circuit geometries.

Comment: I found these online tutorials to be very good: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegralsIntro.aspx

Comment: @AlexRavsky I've only been able to find the Russian version of the book so far (I can't read Russian but I'm curious as to how much I would be able to understand from just the equations and intermediate steps). However, instead of chapter numbers it uses section numbers (543-762 in volume III). Do you know which section it is in?

Answer (score 0):

The Total integral curvature $ \int\int K d A $ and total boundary Rotation $ \int k_g d s $ occuring together in Gauss-Bonnet theorem is a good example in 3D geometry. Consider some applications along/inside a closed loop, for instance:

1) a spherical cap

2) the Temple of Viviani

3) quadrangle on a pseudosphere spanned by four asymptotic lines, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but these are just surface integrals, right? Not *double* surface integrals.

Comment: You wish to know when double surface integral *cannot* be reduced to a single surface integral? For a start, give one specific problem that you encountered.

Comment: No, I'm looking for information and examples on double surface integrals. See the wikipedia article I referred to.